# How to target only the clicked button/div and not all elements

Tags: javascript, show-hide, target, element

Newbie to Javascript here
I have a html/php code, Whats happening right now is when I click the button all elements are shown not just the targeted element. any help most appreciated

HTML/PHP

```
<div class="te contentDiv">
<div class="myContent" style="display:none">
<?=$text?>
<a id="close_btn"     
href="javascript:toggle_visibility('myContent','close_btn','open_btn');"
class="close-more"><?=localised_string('Close')?></a>
</div>    
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    var toggle_visibility = (function () {

    function toggle(cl) {

        var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);

        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            var s = els[i].style;
            s.display = s.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        };
    }
    return function (cl) {

        if (cl instanceof Array) {

            for (var i = 0; i < cl.length; i++) {   
                toggle(cl[i]);
            }

        } else { 
            toggle(cl);
        }
    };
})();
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, I have been working from other peoples examples

Comment: Your code is very odd for it's mixing IDs and class attributes and iterating over all declared elements always toggling every one per invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your invocation of `toggle_visibility()` in HTML isn't matching code in JS for

```
if (cl instanceof Array)
```

isn't `true`, thus it's toggling all buttons declared with **class** `myContent`. `cl` in function returned from `toggle_visibility()` is first argument of invocation, which is `'myContent'` in your case. But I think you want either use `arguments` rather than `cl` there or wrap the list of names in an array on invocation like this:

```
toggle_visibility( [ 'myContent', 'close_btn', 'open_btn' ] );
```

But this won't fix your issue nevertheless.

What about click handler like this:

```
function toggle_visibility(event) {
    event.target.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null).style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    return false;
}
```

Note: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target

In your HTML you might use

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility();">Link</a>
```

See that example in addition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget

Comment: I will have a try and get back.

Comment: Someone else game me this file, Its a bit messed up, I's just trying to get the button open -> show div -> button close -> hide div but at the moment it just selects all to open - all to close  (Newbie just learning JS)

Comment: It's not a shame to be newbie ... Javascript is sometimes hard to understand for long-term coders, too. Your initially posted code, though, isn't simple javascript but is using quite complex approaches in limiting variables scopes, returning functions to invoke, auto-detecting different kinds of parameters passed etc. That's quite much for a beginner ...

Comment: I know its driving me mad but thanks for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can achieve it in one line...

```
 $(".close-more").on("click",function(){$(this).toggle()})
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in post above.

Comment: @cepharum I don't have Jquery, This is another person's file

Comment: I saw that, only a suggestion.